# CMSIS DSP returning Hard Fault (Cortex M0)

Tags: arm, fft, microcontroller, nxp-microcontroller, cmsis

I'm trying to debug this code and identify what's causing a hard fault upon calling the fft method. The program is reading from an ADC via interrupts and every 128 cycles it calculates the FFT of the previous set of cycles.

I have indicated  the line that is causing the fault. Can anyone identify what I am doing wrong?

```
uint16_t dataADC[64];
uint16_t dataFFT[128];
uint16_t magFFT[64];
uint16_t count = 127;

arm_rfft_instance_q15 RealFFT_Instance;
arm_cfft_radix4_instance_q15 MyComplexFFT_Instance;


void ADC_IRQHandler(void){
    /* Read ADC value */
    Chip_ADC_ReadValue(LPC_ADC, ADC_CH0, &dataADC[count]);

    count--;

    if (count == 0){
        NVIC_DisableIRQ(ADC_IRQn);
    }

    Chip_ADC_SetStartMode(LPC_ADC, ADC_START_NOW, ADC_TRIGGERMODE_RISING);
}

/**
 * @brief   main routine for ADC example
 * @return  Function should not exit
 */
int main(void){
    SystemCoreClockUpdate();
    Board_Init();
    Init_ADC_PinMux();
    DEBUGSTR("ADC Demo\r\n");

    //Init FFT
    arm_rfft_init_q15(&RealFFT_Instance, &MyComplexFFT_Instance, 64,0,1);

    /* ADC Init */
    Chip_ADC_Init(LPC_ADC, &ADCSetup);
    Chip_ADC_EnableChannel(LPC_ADC, ADC_CH0, ENABLE);

    /* Enable ADC interrupt*/
    NVIC_ClearPendingIRQ(ADC_IRQn);
    NVIC_EnableIRQ(ADC_IRQn);

    HAID_ADC->INTEN |= 0x0011;

    /* Start A/D conversion */
    Chip_ADC_SetStartMode(LPC_ADC, ADC_START_NOW, ADC_TRIGGERMODE_RISING);

    while (1) {
        if(count == 0){
                NVIC_DisableIRQ(ADC_IRQn);
                arm_rfft_q15(&RealFFT_Instance, (q15_t *)dataADC, (q15_t *)dataFFT); //Causing Hard Fault!
                for(int i = 0; i < 128; i++){
                    dataFFT[i] <<= 8; //scaling
                }
                arm_cmplx_mag_q15((q15_t *)dataFFT, (q15_t *)magFFT, 64);
                count = 63;
                NVIC_EnableIRQ(ADC_IRQn);
        }
        __WFI();
    }
    return 0;
}

#endif
```

Comment: Hard faults are escalations of other faults, either because the handler is missing or because the handler itself faults.  Have you tried unrolling the stack from the hard fault handler to find out what kind of fault is actually occurring?

Comment: Is the second argument `&MyComplexFFT_Instance` to your [`arm_rfft_init_q15`](https://www.keil.com/pack/doc/CMSIS/DSP/html/group__RealFFT.html#ga053450cc600a55410ba5b5605e96245d) call a typo? I wouldn't expect it there (it's there for `f32` type, but not `q15`).

Comment: It looks like very old CMSIS library (I found your init function only in [CMSIS v1.1](http://www.disca.upv.es/aperles/arm_cortex_m3/curset/CMSIS/Documentation/DSP/html/group___r_f_f_t___r_i_f_f_t.html#ga2530ebf44b7f5b559b191ff7265a9120) ). First, you should try latest library.